# Linq group by multiple columns, one of which is selectable

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table consisting of

```
MyDate(DATETIME),
Type nvarchar(255),
PropertyAId(int),
PropertyBId(int),
Data1 (float),
Data2 (float),
...
Data50 (float)
```

I want to return a table grouped by
MyDate,Type, and one of PropertyAId,PropertyBId (depending on user selection)
and sum all of the Data columns.I would prefer summing and selecting Data columns based on prefix or data type, and not having to repeat the same line 50 times

What I have so far is a bit ugly

```
 DataTable dt2 = dt.Clone();
            var grouped = dt.AsEnumerable().
                GroupBy(r => new
                {
                    MyDate = r.Field<DateTime>("MyDate"),
                    PropertyAId = selectedGroupingColumn == "PropertyAId" ? r.Field<int?>("PropertyAId") : null,
                    PropertyBId = selectedGroupingColumn == "PropertyBId" ? r.Field<int?>("PropertyBId") : null,
                    Type  = r.Field<string>("Type")
                });

            foreach (var group in grouped)
            {
                DataRow row = dt2.NewRow();

                foreach (var col in dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>())
                {
                    if (col.ColumnName.StartsWith("Data"))
                    {
                        double sum = 0;
                        if (col.DataType == typeof(double))
                            sum = group.Sum(r => r.Field<double>(col));

                        row.SetField(col.ColumnName, sum);
                    }
                    else
                        row[col.ColumnName] = group.First()[col];

                }
                dt2.Rows.Add(row);
            }

            //dt2.Columns.Remove unselected property and return table
```

Comment: And what have you tried till now? [Ask]

Comment: Please show your work until now.

Comment: added work done so far

Comment: _Data1, Data2,...,Data50_ Someone has problems with database design.

Comment: I know those should have been rows but gotta work with what you have

Comment: If you had a column name beginning with "Data" that isn't a `double`, seems like you'd get an error on the `SetField` - why are you setting it to `0` in the case?

Answer (score 0):

Your logic seems (mostly) sound, but I would suggest just using `selectedGroupingColumn` directly to get the value to group by, and only set the sum for "Data" columns of type `double`:

```
DataTable dt2 = dt.Clone();
var grouped = dt.AsEnumerable().
    GroupBy(r => new {
        MyDate = r.Field<DateTime>("MyDate"),
        GroupingColumnValue = r.Field<int?>(selectedGroupingColumn),
        Type = r.Field<string>("Type")
    });

foreach (var group in grouped) {
    DataRow row = dt2.NewRow();

    foreach (var col in dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>())
        if (col.ColumnName.StartsWith("Data") && col.DataType == typeof(double))
            row.SetField(col.ColumnName, group.Sum(r => r.Field<double>(col)));
        else
            row[col.ColumnName] = group.First()[col];

    dt2.Rows.Add(row);
}
```